# SQL server OPENJSON with multiple where on a filed

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with a `json` field. The `json` schema is the same for all records.

[image]

I want to get just 2 products with `red` or `blue` color and with `brand 1`.
I tried the below query but I know that's not working:

```
SELECT [Id], [JName], [JValue]
FROM   [Product]
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Json])
WITH ([JName] NVARCHAR(50) '$.name', [JValue] NVARCHAR(50) '$.value')
WHERE 
    (CASE WHEN [JName]=N'color' AND [JValue] IN (N'red', N'red') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) &
    (CASE WHEN [JName]=N'brand' AND [JValue] IN (N'brand 1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

so, how should I write this query?

Comment: When you say you want 2 products, what do you mean? In your data above you have three products (Product1, 2 and 4) matching your criteria: red or blue and brand 1. If that was a typo then you can quite easily achieve this with a `CTE` and in the `SELECT` clause you join to yourself. I have that code here, but I just wanted to clarify first about those two products.

Comment: @NielsBerglund I know there's 3 product, but i just want the first two product that matching the criteria. It's paging. I know i must use OFFSET but that's not working in this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit unsure of what you are asking:

How to get data matching your criteria (red or blue and brand1), since your posted query will not get what you want.

OR

How to do an OFFSET for pagination purposes.

OR

Both.

Anyway, after my initial comment above (but before your reply), I wrote a query which would give you what you want (red or blue and Brand1).

After your reply I modified the query to do `OFFSET` as well:

```
;WITH prod
AS
(
  SELECT [Id], [JName], [JValue]
  FROM   dbo.tb_Product
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([Json])
  WITH ([JName] NVARCHAR(50) '$.name', [JValue] NVARCHAR(50) '$.value')
  )
SELECT p1.Id, p1.JValue AS Color, p2.JValue AS Brand
FROM prod p1
JOIN prod p2
  ON p1.Id = p2.Id
WHERE p1.JName = 'Color'
  AND p1.JValue IN ('red', 'blue')
  AND p2.JName = 'Brand'
  AND p2.JValue IN ('Brand1')
ORDER BY p1.ID
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

I hope this is somewhat what you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's work. but it's not return the first two product, it's return the first two record from join and both of them are Product 1

Comment: With due respect it's hard to answer when you change the requirements as you go along. Perhaps if you asked the question is such a way that it clearly stated what you want to know, and perhaps also include an example of the result you want, based on the JSON data you posted in the question. That would make it a lot easier to come up with the answer you want.

Comment: you helped me a lot, thanks. just a question, can you give me a tip for that pagination problem?

Comment: For pagination, use the code in my answer. You should probably wrap it in a stored procedure, so you can send in parameter values for offset and row to fetch.